# a question about the proof of theorem 5.3 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is on [page 33](http://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&pg=PA33) of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

Let $Y$ be an affine variety, and Sing $Y$ be the set of singular points of $Y$. Suppose we already know that Sing $Y$ is a close subset of $Y$, now we need to show that $X := Y -$Sing $Y$, which is an open subset of $Y$, is not empty.

In order to do this, the author considers a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$ which is birationally equivalent to $Y$.

> Since birational varieties have isomorphic open subsets, we reduce to the case of a hypersurface.

I have three questions about this.

1. As in [Corollary 4.5(i)(ii)](http://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&pg=PA26) of this same book, two varieties are birationally equivalent if and only if they each contains **one** nonempty open subsets isomorphic to each other. Does this mean the existence of an isomorphism correspondence between **all** the open subsets of the two varieties?
2. Another question is, let $Y,Y'$ be birationally equivalent varieties, and $X = Y -$Sing $Y$, $X'=Y'-$Sing $Y'$, then is it true that $X$ and $X'$ must be isomorphic? Combining with the first question, if the isomorphism correspondence between the open subsets of $Y$ and $Y'$ does exist, does it necessarily corresponds $X$ and $X'$?
3. I think the answer to both of my questions must be negative, since the open subset might be the variety itself. But **how can I understand the proof? Why can the author just consider $Y$ as a hypersurface?**

Thanks.

Comment: If I am not mistaken for very trivial matters, you can always projectize an affine variety into a projective variety. So you can view an affine variety as a part of a projective variety when $x_{n}=1$ or something. But not sure if that is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For question 1, the answer is no. Consider $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $\mathbb{A}^1-\{pt\}$. $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not isomorphic to any proper open subset of itself (this is an exercise somewhere in Chapter 1 of Hartshorne).

The answer to problem 2 is also no. If $Y=\mathbb{A}^1$ and $Y'=\mathbb{A}^1-\{pt\}$, then $X=Y$ and $X'=Y'$, so they're obviously non-isomorphic. On the other hand something close to the statement of 2 is true- $X$ and $X'$ are birational. Since $\operatorname{Sing}(Z)\subset Z$ is a proper closed subset for all varieties $Z$, we know that $X$ and $Y$ are birational, and similarly for $X'$ and $Y'$, so $X$ is birational to $X'$.

In reading the proof of I.5.3, note that the first sentence of paragraph 2 of the proof is "To show $\operatorname{Sing} Y$ is a proper closed subset of $Y$, we first apply I.4.9 to get $Y$ birational to a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$". So we go and look up I.4.9, which tells us that any variety $X$ of dimension $r$ is birational to a hypersurface $Y\subset \mathbb{P}^{r+1}$. The proof is as follows (all of this is essentially Hartshorne's proof with some extra comments from me):

The function field $K$ of $X$ is a finitely generated extension field of $k$. Since $k$ is algebraically closed, it is perfect, and by a theorem in commutative algebra, $K/k$ is separably generated, so we can find a transcendence basis $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in K$ so that $K$ is a finite separable extension of $k(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$. By the theorem of the primitive element, we can find one further element $y\in K$, algebraic over $k(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ such that $K=k(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y)$. Since $y$ is algebraic over $k(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, it satisfies a polynomial equation with coefficients which are rational functions in the $x_i$s. Clearing denominators, we get an irreducible polynomial $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n,y)=0$. This gives a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^{r+1}$ with function field $K$, which exactly means a hypersurface birational to $X$. In order to get this hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^{r+1}$, we use the operation of projective closure, from exercise 2.9 of chapter I.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The examples are interesting and the fact that $X,X'$ are birational is new to me. However, what was not clear in my previous post of the question was that I also needed to know how I could understand the proof.

Comment: Updated with explanation for question 3.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I think my essential trouble is understanding this: suppose $Y,Y'$ birationally equivalent and let $X = Y -$Sing$Y$, $X'=Y'-$ Sing$Y'$, then why $X' = \emptyset$ implies $X = \emptyset$.

Comment: Suppose $Y$ is birational to a hypersurface $Y'$. If every point of $Y$ is singular, then every point of some open subset of $Y'$ is singular. Since nonempty open sets are dense in irreducible varieties, we have that $\frac{df}{dx_i}$ are zero on all points of $Y'$, so the singular set of our hypersurface is in fact our entire hypersurface. Does this help?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for your help and patience.